# Using useReducer within useContext

Tags: reactjs

This code used to run before, but I get a 'rules of hooks' error now.

What am I missing?

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from 'react';

import initialState from './initialState';
import reducer from './reducer';
import actions from './actions';

const uiContext = createContext();

const uiProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  return (
      <uiContext.Provider
        value={{ state, actions: actions(dispatch) }}
        children={children}
      />
  );
};

export { uiContext, uiProvider };
```

Comment: Can you be more specific in what error you get?

Comment: "React Hook "useReducer" is called in function "uiProvider" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks"

Comment: It might be that because your component is in lower case, linter is showing an error (does't recognize your function as react component). Try to rename it to UIProvider.

Answer (score 0):

Danko's comment above solved this. Putting a capital letter first solved the issue, thank you!